# Объясните кусок кода из справки expressjs.com

Tags: node.js, express

Пытаюсь назначить файлам, хранящимся на моем сервере, новые пути, чтобы не показывать пути с самого сервера. В идеале бы еще и имя файла изменить в пути, который увидит пользователь.

Я нагуглил код в документации expressjs.com, который отдает статические файлы с сервера. Исходник можно найти по ссылке: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile. Его пример ниже:

```
app.get('/file/:name', function (req, res, next) {
  var options = {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), //-- вопросы касаются этой строчки
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
      'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
      'x-sent': true
    }
  }

  var fileName = req.params.name
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName)
    }
  })
});
```

У меня появилось несколько вопросов:

- папка "public" в понимании сервера точно такая же как и папка "static", заданная следующим образом? `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));` В такой папке я храню часто используемые файлы: логотипы, скрипты, стили.
- Чем является "path" в этой строке? root: `path.join(__dirname, 'public'),`. Мой сервер не понимает, что это значит и выдает "ReferenceError: path is not defined".

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment:  спасибо, большое!

Comment: @andreymal может быть Вы знаете и о различии (или его отсутствии) между моей папкой "static" и папкой из примера "public"?  вопрос появляется, потому что они объявляются по-разному